# What does the RTTSum and RTTSum2 represent in a ASA SLA monitor?

Tags: cisco-asa

I have enabled the SLA monitor on an ASA, and I was wondering what the RTTSum and RTTSum2  Metric Represents?

RTT stands for "Rout Trip Time" I am having trouble figuring what the RTTSum actually represent, how would I read it and apply it to troubleshooting?

```
Modification time: 16:46:11.982 EST Mon Sep 16 2013
Number of Octets Used by this Entry: 1480
Number of operations attempted: 197
Number of operations skipped: 0
Current seconds left in Life: Forever
Operational state of entry: Active
Last time this entry was reset: Never
Connection loss occurred: FALSE
Timeout occurred: FALSE
Over thresholds occurred: FALSE
Latest RTT (milliseconds): 10
Latest operation start time: 17:18:51.982 EST Mon Sep 16 2013
Latest operation return code: OK
RTT Values:
RTTAvg: 10  RTTMin: 10  RTTMax: 10
NumOfRTT: 3 RTTSum: 30  RTTSum2: 300
```

And another example

```
Number of Octets Used by this Entry: 1480
Number of operations attempted: 243
Number of operations skipped: 0
Current seconds left in Life: Forever
Operational state of entry: Active
Last time this entry was reset: Never
Connection loss occurred: FALSE
Timeout occurred: FALSE
Over thresholds occurred: FALSE
Latest RTT (milliseconds): 13
Latest operation start time: 17:26:31.992 EST Mon Sep 16 2013
Latest operation return code: OK
RTT Values:
RTTAvg: 13  RTTMin: 10  RTTMax: 20
NumOfRTT: 3 RTTSum: 40  RTTSum2: 600
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RTTSum](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=rttMonLatestJitterOperRTTSum&translate=Translate) is the sum of samples, divide it by sample count and you've got arithmetic mean.

[RTTSum2](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=rttMonLatestJitterOperRTTSum2&translate=Translate) is sum of squares of samples, you need it for example to derive standard deviation.